# Linq To Sql Conversation In Wcf Service

Tags: sql-server, linq, wcf

Can you please provide an answer following sql query to linq . I have some knowledge about linq but i am confused about sql reader object ..

```
 public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  Account_Type,Account_Fees,Account_Balance,Over_Draft_Limit FROM Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number = '" + accountNumber.Account_Number + "'", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //read the result of the execute command.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details
                accountNumber.Account_Type = reader["Account_Type"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Account_Fee = reader["Account_Fees"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
            }
            return accountNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, your code is very dangerous, its vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Second, what exactly is your question, is there an error with the code provided, or does it not return something you require?

Comment: I want to convert this query to linq . There is no error

Comment: Start reading here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx. We can't start a LINQ class here.

Comment: I did not ask you to start class in this site . What i asked is that how to use sql reader object in linq @gert Annold

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. First choose which ORM you want to turn to if you want to convert a SQL query to LINQ. Once you've done that you won't be dealing with DbReaders any  more.

Comment: I already chosen the the orm and i wrote this ado.net code in wcf service method implementation .the entity framework generate the required  code . I was confused that how can i use read object . Thats ok .i got the answer

Comment: Linq is batter then ado.net . With linq query i got complation errors and others benefits as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to have DbContext which you must instantiate in using(usual practice):

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    var results = (from ad in db.Current_Account_Details
                  where ad.Account_Number == accountNumber.Account_Number
                  select ad).ToList();
}
```

Make sure you have created the object data [model from database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx).

I do not get the other part of your post but this would be the general idea of how to write Linq2Entities queries.

Comment: Thank you very much @rob